# Read from socket return value in c++

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I need to enforce the return value of `read` from a socket to equal to zero *without* closing connection.

I read the following statement in a page saying:

> If an end-of-file condition is received or the connection is closed, 0 is returned.

But I don't know how to make it receive that condition after the string I have sent.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you want this? How else would the receiver know how much the `read` call received?

Comment: i  want this to make both sides can communicates each other, but also i used something like this in my code :    while ((n = read(sock,rcv_buffer,len)) != 0) to guarantee the whole message recieved .,then server can reply ., and so on ..

Comment: You might have the sending end emitting a whole bunch of bytes in one single `send` or `write` syscall and the recieving end needing several `read` or `recv` to get it. In other words, TCP/IP transmission may be fragmented (by the network).

Comment: Reading in a loop while `read` returns non-zero is _not_ a good idea, as you miss errors that way. For your problem, the answer by Mat is the way to go, either send the message length or send an end-of-message marker in the stream.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you can't do that.

If you want `read` to return zero, you need to close the socket. If you don't want to close the socket, you need to signal "end-of-communication" or "end-of-message" as part of your protocol.

A common way of doing that is prefixing each message with its length. That way the receiving side knows when it's read a complete message and do whatever it wants with it.

Comment: i am trying to runaway from using my protocol ., this is because i am trying to find other way ..

Comment: You can run away from whatever you like, but that won't change how `read` on sockets works. A zero return means that "side" of the socket was closed.

Comment: if you please to see my problem illustration in the following comments at the next answer ., thank u .

Comment: @sana: I understand your problem. You can't solve it by expecting `read` to return zero without closing the socket. That's not negotiable. It's a "fact of life" you cannot change. You **need** to implement a protocol yourself if you don't want to close the socket.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the peer's read() or recv() to return zero, you must either close the socket or shut it down for output. In either case you can't sent anything else afterwards. If that constraint doesn't suit you, you will have to revise your requirement, as it doesn't make sense.

Comment: thank you for the answer ., BUT in my case i had to remain both reading and writing available on both sides also i have to gurantee that all the sent msg from one has all revieved to the reciever , by putting read statement in a while loop untill n reaches zero .,as this :   while ((n = read(sock,rcv_buffer,len)) != 0) which i think this what may raised my problem .,do u have any solution ?

Comment: note that i had to put read in a while lop in case of fragmentation occurred in the message at the physical layer .,!

Comment: @sana There are no 'buts' about it. Either you close or shut down the socket or you can't get the read to return zero. So you have to adjust your requirement. – EJP 11 hours ago

Answer (score 1):

Both the "end of file condition" and the "connection closed" condition tell the receiver that no more data can be received on this socket. You cannot simulate that by sending some magic data.

Besides of calling `close` on the socket you can use `shutdown(2)` on the socket to only close either the reading side or the writing side. This might help in limited cases but not in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need some multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html).

You definitely need to read some good material like [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) or [Advanced Unix Programming](http://basepath.com/aup).

If you need the TCP/IP transmission to transit application messages, you need to care about packaging and fragmenting explicitly yourself (either by having fixed-size messages, or by having some way to know the logical message size during transmission). Be aware that TCP/IP transmission can be fragmented by the network.